# Как прочитать с консоли строку неизвестной заранее длины не используя string?

Tags: c++, массивы, char, строки

Я прекрасно понимаю, что можно использовать класс string и просто написать cin>>  str; а затем получить количество элементов.
Я даже видел веселое решение при помощи malloc и realloc функций из C.
но все же, интересно, есть ведь какой-то способ при помощи средств C++, а конкретно их потоков ввода и стандартных строк в виде массива символов прочитать из консоли строку, не имея понятия о ее размере, получить впоследствии ее размер и положить в динамически выделенный массив такого размера??
Вопрос не к спеху и не для какого-то задания, все чисто ради интереса, так что ваши ответы, типа "не парься и пользуйся тем, что дают" также приветствуются )

Comment: Ну, если вы пишете на C++, то стандартная строка и есть `std::string`. С ним просто. Если вы принципиально не пользуетесь идиоматическими строками, то вам таки придётся заниматься ручным выделением памяти через `new[]`/`delete[]` или тот же malloc/realloc. В C++ специальных других средств нету, т. к. строкой по сути считается `std::string`.

Comment: Стандартной функции я не знаю. Можно считывать посимвольно, выделив внутри `char *buffer` какого-то фиксированнового размера, по достижению предела емеости буфера, выделить, скажем, вдвое больший и т.д. пока не встретится `EOF` или символ новой строкию

Comment: Удалось добиться разве что такого https://ideone.com/nzjJa6, но тут важно, что ввод производиться не с консоли пользователем, а подаётся "напрямую". В консоли считать заново не удавалось ни в какую, все сбрасывается после нажатия `enter`

Comment: Можно ещё конечно использовать `std::stringstream`, но мне кажется что в рамках этой задачи это будет читом :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cin >> str;` запишет только до первого разделителя: http://ideone.com/Y5CJxD.

Если под строкой понимается последовательность, которая заканчивается переводом строки (`'\n'`), то вам: `std::getline()` нужен: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/

А так, `std::string` это и так стандартное средство в C++. Если же хочется извратиться, то нужно читать блоками, проверять - есть ли перевод строки и агрегировать код, но лишнее нужно как-то хранить между вызовами. Либо, что проще, но медленнее - читать посимвольно, проверяя конец строки, например так:

```
istream& getline(istream& is, char *&buffer)
{
    std::istream::sentry s(is);
    if (s)
    {
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char> it(is);
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char> end;

        size_t size = 64;
        size_t grow = 64;
        size_t len  = 0;

        buffer = new char[size];

        while (it != end && *it != '\n') 
        {
            if (len == (size - 1)) 
            {
                buffer = buffer_realloc(buffer, size, size + grow);
                size += grow;
            }

            buffer[len++] = *it++;
        }

        buffer[len] = '\0';
    }

    return is;
}
```

Здесь я не привожу функцию `buffer_realloc()` - она простая. Использовать как-то так:

```
char *line = nullptr;
while (getline(std::cin, line))
{
    if (line) 
    {
        cout << line << endl;
        delete[] line;
    }
}
```

Либо вот вариант, где использует вектор:

```
istream& getline(istream& is, vector<char> &buffer)
{
    std::istream::sentry s(is);
    if (s)
    {
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char> it(is);
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char> end;

        const size_t grow = 64;
        buffer.reserve(grow);

        while (it != end && *it != '\n') 
        {
            if (buffer.size() == buffer.capacity() - 1) 
            {
                buffer.reserve(buffer.size() + grow);
            }

            buffer.push_back(*it++);
        }
        buffer.push_back('\0');
    }

    return is;
}
```

Использовать как-то так:

```
vector<char> line;
while (getline(std::cin, line))
{
    if (!line.empty()) 
    {
        cout << line.data() << endl;
        line.clear();
    }
}
```

Тут реаллокация памяти ложится на плечи vector'а. От вас только почистить его (а можно и в гетлайн всунуть). Плюс бонусом сразу длинна строки за O(1): `line.size() - 1`

Вот законченные примеры:

- http://ideone.com/Huj4eQ
- http://ideone.com/CxNfg4

Но повторюсь: `std::string` стандартны для С++. Я слабо представляю условия, где есть потоки, но нет строк :)

Answer (score 1):

По сути, реализация cin выглядит так (игнорируя тот факт, что оба потока и строка шаблоны):

```
std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& in, std::string& value) {
    std::istream::sentry cerberos(in);
    if (cerberos) {
        value.erase();
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char> it(in), end;
        if (it != end) {
            std::ctype<char> const& ctype(std::use_facet<std::ctype<char> >(in.getloc()));
            std::back_insert_iterator<std::string> to(value);
            std::streamsize n(0), width(in.width()? in.width(): std::string::max_size());
            for (; it != end && n != width && !ctype.is(std::ctype_base::space, *it); ++it, ++to) {
                *to = *it;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        in.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
    }
    return in;
}
```

Выводы думаю вы можете сделать сами.

Answer (score -1):

Немного странный вопрос, т.к. если нужно сделать то же самое, что можно сделать с помощью `std::string` - следует хотя бы посмотреть реализацию `operator>>` для потока ввода и строкового аргумента.

Основной смысл в том, что читаем посимвольно и посимвольно же добавляем. В итоге получим ещё и некоторое подобие реализации `std::vector` для символьного типа.

Comment: Причина отрицательного голоса будет озвучена?